# How to get full path in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

Can anyone please suggest how to get full path in jsp?

Iam creating an image in some location in java class, and when im trying to access this location path in jsp, it is not showing the full path.

Comment: What do you mean by full path?

Comment: Im not able to get an image full path from my local system in jsp

Comment: Can you show some code and examples of what you expect and what you're getting?

Answer (score 9):

```
<html>
<head><title>Absolute Path</title></head>
Absolute Path is:<%= getServletContext().getRealPath("/") %> 
</html>
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 5):

You can use real path.

```
 String webRootPath = application.getRealPath("/").replace('\\', '/');
```

or

```
   String webRootPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/").replace('\\', '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to create your own resources folder inside your application folder and store all your resources(images in your case) there.

You can then access it using this:

```
String path=application.getRealPath("/resourcesfolder/image.jpg");
```

Comment: What happens in case the application is undeployed? Won't you lose all images added after deployment or rather while in production?