# Access all Struts project files in cPanel

Tags: java, web-applications, cpanel, whm

Technologies: Java, Struts, MySQL, goDaddy VPS.

all servers have one common DB.

Downloaded database from there. But somehow in cPanel file system, I can not see any project files. I found WEB-INF/ with empty class folder and empty lib folder inside.

So, How do I get all Struts project files and setup in local computer?

Comment: Too broad. See [ask].

Comment: I think you can ask goDaddy for your application location.

Comment: I asked them but they don't have access of server for safety purpose.

Comment: OK, don't worry. You also can upload a jsp containing `<html>
<head><title>Absolute Path</title></head>
Absolute Path is:<%= getServletContext().getRealPath("/") %> 
</html>` to your application on VPS, then open that in your browser, then it should print what you want to know for you :) see more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057339/how-to-get-full-path-in-jsp please try.

Comment: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Deploy+Java+Applications